# Difference between $\nabla(\nabla . F)$ and $\nabla^2F$, where $F$ is a vector function

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

I recently started vector calculus and saw that following identity

$\nabla\times(\nabla\times F)=\nabla(\nabla.F)-\nabla^2F$

But aren't  $\nabla(\nabla.F)$ and $\nabla^2F$ the same or I am missing something.

In a scalar function $f$ we define $\nabla^2f = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z^2}$, is there a similar definition for $\nabla^2F$, where $F$ is a vector function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Typically $\nabla^2$, the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator), is $\nabla\cdot\nabla$, is an operator which maps scalar functions to scalar functions. Clearly
$$\nabla \nabla \cdot \neq \nabla \cdot \nabla$$
the first is the gradient of a divergence, the second is the divergence of the gradient.

Wikipedia *defines* the [vector Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Laplacian) $\nabla^2 F$, for vectorial $F$, by the formula you give. In Cartesian coordinates, the vector Laplacian is the scalar Laplacian applied component-wise,
$$\nabla^2 [f_x,f_y,f_z] = [\nabla^2 f_x,\nabla^2 f_y,\nabla^2
 f_z]$$

Comment: I might be appearing stupid , but I want to confirm one thing : $\nabla$ is defined as $\nabla = i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+j\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+k\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, which is a vector operator . Now that definition of $\nabla f$ is fine when $f$ is scalar as this is seen as a scalar multiplication.
Continued in next comment

Comment: But in case of vector function $F$ , I think $\nabla F$ has no meaning since operations between vectors are only dot and cross product . But from the definition of vector Laplacian we are saying that $\nabla.(\nabla F)$ is defined that is the operation in the braces gradient of a vector field is also defined . 

So finally does $\nabla F$ have a meaning ?

Comment: It is as you say, $\nabla F$ does not have a meaning. The vector Laplacian is an entirely new operator, which confusingly is still written as $\nabla^2 F$, but cannot be interpreted as $\nabla \cdot \nabla F$

Comment: Thank you , so vector laplacian is a completely new operator thx

Comment: @VinayVarahabhotla $\nabla F$ and $\nabla^2F=\nabla\cdot\nabla F$ can be given a meaning using ideas from differential geometry, but it is probably a little too advance for you now.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $\nabla^2 F$ is defined to be the divergence of the gradient, i.e. $\nabla\cdot \nabla F$. On the other hand, $\nabla(\nabla \cdot F)$ is the gradient of the divergence.

Comment: "Divergence of the gradient" only works for scalar-valued function.

Comment: I might be appearing stupid , but I want to confirm one thing : $\nabla$ is defined as $\nabla = i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+j\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+k\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, which is a vector operator . Now that definition of $\nabla f$ is fine when $f$ is scalar as this is seen as a scalar multiplication.
Continued in next comment

Comment: But in case of vector function $F$ , I think $\nabla F$ has no meaning since operations between vectors are only dot and cross product . But from the definition of vector Laplacian we are saying that $\nabla.(\nabla F)$ is defined that is the operation in the braces gradient of a vector field is also defined . 

So finally does $\nabla F$ have a meaning ?